# C++ Template Vector Operation Overload

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I've got a bit of a tricky proposition.

I'd like to create a template of `typedef std::vector<T*> BasicVector;`

This is because I'd like to overload a method that would apply to all basic vectors

```
sf::Packet& operator <<(sf::Packet& packet, BasicVector& p);
```

This doesn't quite work... How do I accomplish something like this?

```
typedef template<typename T> std::vector<typename T*> BasicVector;
```

Or maybe something like

```
sf::Packet& operator <<(sf::Packet& packet, std::vector<T*>& p);
```

Comment: "typedef template<typename T> std::vector<typename T*> BasicVector;" can be done with "template<typename T> using BasicVector = std::vector<T*>;"

Comment: Not sure what the purpose is here though.

Comment: Thanks @jhoffman0x, see my answer below for what I'm attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

For

```
typedef template<typename T> std::vector<typename T*> BasicVector;
```

You need [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
template<class T> using BasicVector = std::vector<T*>;
```

But you still can't pass only *BasicVector* to a function. It's only shortener. For std::vector< int*>, for example, you will write BasicVector< int>.

And, yes, the only way to do what you want with operator << is make operator << template

So, the complete solution is:

```
template<class T> using BasicVector = std::vector<T*>;

template<typename T>
sf::Packet& operator <<(sf::Packet& packet, const BasicVector<T>& v)
{
    packet << (uint32_t)v.size();

    // Or typename BasicVector<T>::value_type elem
    std::for_each(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](T* elem)
        {
            // *it is a pointer elem. Are you sure you need a pointer ?
            packet << *elem;    
        });

    return packet;
}
```

Comment: Ah! This is close. I'll play around with this and see what I get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for is something like this. It's subtle but simple.

It's a tad messy, and would be nice if we could typedef a `std::vector<T*>` but that's not such a big deal.

```
// Packs a basic const std::vector into a packet.
template<typename T>
sf::Packet& operator <<(sf::Packet& packet, const std::vector<T*>& v)
{
    packet << (uint32_t)v.size();

    for (typename std::vector<T*>::iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end(); ++it)
        packet << *it;

    return packet;
}
```